# How to create separate projects for server and client? (express and js)

Tags: javascript, express

My backend is built in express with socket.io and my frontend in plain js.

How is it possible to have them in different projects (in different repos on github) but still have them work together (that the client knows where the server is so to say)?

Do I have to sync them somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in different repositories. The client will communicate with the server using its url.

When you run the server it is on a specific host (any address like localhost or any ip or domain plus a port). The client just need to know this hostname and port.

Comment: It seems to work with Live Server only through vs code. But 404 when I go to localhost. I have this on my index.js on client: const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');